# Hover on a href view screenshot of site

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, hover, href, preview

I have some links like "[domain](http://www.google.com)"
i want to have a preview image of the url link when i mouseover it.
is this possible with something like an iframe?
can someone help me with this?

sincerely Rene,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for a mouse over that displays an image (thumbnail of domain.com). For the mouse over, there are many scripts available: search for "javascript tooltip" ([jQuery tools](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.html) for example).

To get a thumbnail of "domain.com", you need to use a web service like [URL2PNG](http://url2png.com/) or [Browshot](http://browshot.com/).

Comment: thank you i will try that. But i would like to have a frame instead of a thumbnail is this possible?